# Style input range before and after

Tags: html, css

I was following [this method](http://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/) from CSS-Tricks to style an input range and was trying to use the before and after pseudo classes. Below is the code I have tried:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #fff;
}
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick. Can someone help me how to style the slider track. I need a **pure CSS solution**. Essentially I want it to [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRp5q.png).

I will also paste the code from CSS-Tricks:

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 18px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -14px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #367ebd;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2a6495;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3071a9;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}
```

Comment: Inputs don't allow for :before and :after pseudo elements, you'll have to try a different way.

Comment: You are missing quotes

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in Firefox and IE -

```
// Mozilla    
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    background: #cc1a1a;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
// IE
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #CC1A1A;
    border: 0 solid #000101;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #000000, 0 0 0 #0d0d0d;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #c0c0c0;
    border: 0 solid #000101;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #000000, 0 0 0 #0d0d0d;
}
```

Only one way was for Chrome `:before` and `:after`,  isn't supported any more (since March 2016). The best I found - is http://rangeslider.js.org/. Also it works fine with Angular JS - https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider

Answer (score 3):

it's possible!
if your thumb does not have to be bigger than the progress bar.

some css wizard came up with this: https://codepen.io/noahblon/pen/OyajvN

it uses a box-shadow on the thumb to make the part before the thumb look a different color. important is that the range has overflow hidden to make it work thats why the thumb cant be bigger than the track.

```css
    body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}

input[type="range"] { 
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0; /* iOS */
}

::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ddd;
}

/*
 * 1. Set to 0 width and remove border for a slider without a thumb
 */
::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 20px; /* 1 */
    height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: -100vw 0 0 100vw dodgerblue;
    border: 2px solid #999; /* 1 */
}

::-moz-range-track {
    height: 40px;
    background: #ddd;
}

::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: -100vw 0 0 100vw dodgerblue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-ms-fill-lower { 
    background: dodgerblue;
}

::-ms-thumb { 
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    height: 40px;
    width: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-ms-ticks-after { 
    display: none; 
}

::-ms-ticks-before { 
    display: none; 
}

::-ms-track { 
    background: #ddd;
    color: transparent;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
}

::-ms-tooltip { 
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="25">
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a delayed reply here:

A **pure CSS solution** is not possible cross-browser here - IE is the only one that makes this possible via `::-ms-fill-lower` and `::-ms-fill-upper`

For a full cross-browser solution you'll need to use js. There's an example here that updates CSS gradients with the input's value to do roughly what you're after: http://codepen.io/ryanttb/pen/fHyEJ

You can also find information about this in this answer to a similar question: [Style lower and upper fill in HTML5 range input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283332/style-lower-and-upper-fill-in-html5-range-input#answer-28283806)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to do progress indication (i.e. to have different styles on different sides of the handle) purely in CSS *across browsers*.

Here's an idea how to do it easily with a bit of javascript code:
https://css-tricks.com/sliding-nightmare-understanding-range-input/#the-range-progress-fill-component

Here's a tool that generates CSS based on that method:
https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler

Example:

```js
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"].slider-progress')) {
  e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value);
  e.style.setProperty('--min', e.min == '' ? '0' : e.min);
  e.style.setProperty('--max', e.max == '' ? '100' : e.max);
  e.addEventListener('input', () => e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value));
}
```

```css
/*generated with Input range slider CSS style generator (version 20201223)
https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler*/
input[type=range].styled-slider {
  height: 2.8em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*progress support*/
input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress {
  --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
  --ratio: calc((var(--value) - var(--min)) / var(--range));
  --sx: calc(0.5 * 2.8em + var(--ratio) * (100% - 2.8em));
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/*webkit*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 2.8em;
  height: 2.8em;
  border-radius: 1.4em;
  background: #1381A9;
  border: 0.3em solid #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: calc(1em * 0.5 - max(2.8em * 0.5,0.3em));
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #D0D0D0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #0E6180;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #A8A8A8;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  background: #18A5D9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #DBDBDB;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#666666,#666666) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #D0D0D0;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#404040,#404040) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #A8A8A8;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#8C8C8C,#8C8C8C) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #DBDBDB;
}

/*mozilla*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: max(calc(2.8em - 0.3em - 0.3em),0px);
  height: max(calc(2.8em - 0.3em - 0.3em),0px);
  border-radius: 1.4em;
  background: #1381A9;
  border: 0.3em solid #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #D0D0D0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #0E6180;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-moz-range-track {
  background: #A8A8A8;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb:active {
  background: #18A5D9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-moz-range-track {
  background: #DBDBDB;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#666666,#666666) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #D0D0D0;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#404040,#404040) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #A8A8A8;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#8C8C8C,#8C8C8C) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #DBDBDB;
}

/*ms*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb {
  width: 2.8em;
  height: 2.8em;
  border-radius: 1.4em;
  background: #1381A9;
  border: 0.3em solid #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #D0D0D0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb:hover {
  background: #0E6180;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-ms-track {
  background: #A8A8A8;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb:active {
  background: #18A5D9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-ms-track {
  background: #DBDBDB;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
  margin: -undefined 0 -undefined -undefined;
  background: #666666;
  border: none;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #404040;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #8C8C8C;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="styled-slider slider-progress" style="width: 50em;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

If anybody is facing this same issue, here is a (selfmade) generator for generating the (pure) css for such a progress-bar:

https://antvil.github.io/css-sos/sos/progress/

Generated Example:

[image: example progress-bar]

Tested for: firefox, chrome, edge, opera, safari

**But be aware that it sometimes breaks for webkit browsers, because border-radius for the progress cannot be implemented**