# How to change the color of slider-runnable-track on select using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-selectors

I have to change the slider track color on select.But I am unable to get it. I need the change the color, while it slides.

CSS:

```
/* Styles go here */

.text-size-slider {
  line-height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.text-size-slider .small-letter,.text-size-slider .big-letter
{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-size-slider .slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.text-size-slider .slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.text-size-slider .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(192, 35, 74, 0.85);;
  border: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="text-size-slider">
  <span class="pointer" style="left:{{position}}px;">
    <span>{{textSize}}</span>
  </span>
  <span class="small-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: min + unit }"> 
    <small>T</small>T</span>
  <input type="range" min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" step="{{ step || 0 }}"
         ng-model="textSize" class="slider" value="{{ value }}"
         ng-change="updatepointer()" />
  <span class="big-letter" ng-style="{fontSize: max + unit }"> 
    <small>T</small>T</span>
</div>
```

Comment: cam you make an working example?

Comment: @SahilDhir https://plnkr.co/edit/nu3tXbMeakDM34bWL53V?p=preview

Comment: you need to use some jquery here.. Not possible with css only.

Comment: @ Sahil Dhir with javascript,Is it possible?

Comment: You should note that the output looks different in Firefox

Comment: yes it is possible with jqury plus your current code is only feasible with webkit browser

Comment: @ Sahil Dhir ok,can You say me how to do with jquery anf for firefox,

Comment: firefox has `::-moz-range-progress` and IE/Edge has `::-ms-fill-lower` but they are still early in development. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283332/style-lower-and-upper-fill-in-html5-range-input

Answer (score 1):

I hope my code work for you. It is only with CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        
    input[type='range'] {
      width: 200px;
      height: 3px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      background-color: #1682fb;
      display: flex;
      outline: none;
        border: none;
    } 
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      height: 5px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin-top: -10px;
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      width: 15px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #1682fb; 
      box-shadow: 5px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,  10px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
     21px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 22px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    23px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 24px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 25px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    26px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 27px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 28px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    29px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 30px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 31px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    32px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 33px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 34px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    35px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 36px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 37px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    38px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 39px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 40px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    41px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 42px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 43px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    44px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 45px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 46px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    47px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 48px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 49px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    50px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 51px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 52px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    53px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 54px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 55px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    56px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 57px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 58px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    59px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 60px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 61px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    62px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 63px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 64px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    65px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 66px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 67px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    68px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 69px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 70px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    71px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 72px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 73px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    74px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 75px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 76px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    77px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 78px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 79px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    80px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 81px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 82px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    83px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 84px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 85px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    86px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 87px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 88px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    89px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 90px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 91px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    92px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 93px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 94px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    95px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 96px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 97px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    98px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 99px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 100px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    101px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 102px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 103px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    104px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 105px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 106px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    107px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 108px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 109px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    110px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 111px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 112px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    113px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 114px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 115px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    116px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 117px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 118px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    119px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 120px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 121px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    122px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 123px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 124px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    125px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 126px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 127px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    128px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 129px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 130px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    131px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 132px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 133px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    134px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 135px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 136px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    137px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 138px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 139px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    140px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 141px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 142px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    143px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 144px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 145px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    146px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 147px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 148px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    149px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 150px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 151px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    152px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 153px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 154px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    155px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 156px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 157px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    158px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 159px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 160px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    161px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 162px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 163px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    164px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 165px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 166px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    167px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 168px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 169px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    170px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 171px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 172px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    173px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 174px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 175px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    176px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 177px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 178px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    179px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 180px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 181px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    182px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 183px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 184px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    185px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 186px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 187px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    188px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 189px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 190px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    191px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 192px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 193px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    194px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 195px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 196px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    197px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 198px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 199px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    200px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 201px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 202px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    203px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 204px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 205px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    206px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 207px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 208px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    209px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 210px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 211px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    212px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 213px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 214px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    215px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 216px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 217px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    218px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 219px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 220px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    221px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 222px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 223px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    224px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 225px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 226px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    227px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 228px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 229px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    230px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 231px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 232px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    233px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 234px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 235px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    236px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 237px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 238px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6,
    239px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6, 240px 0 0 -6px #e3e4e6;
  margin-top: 0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 15px;padding-top: 10px;padding-right:3px;width: 200px;">
    <input type="range" name="" id="" min="=0" max="100" step="1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

tricks.