# After and before elements for -webkit-slider-thumb

Tags: css, styling, pseudo-element

I am trying to add after or before elements for `-webkit-slider-thumb` like `-webkit-slider-thumb:after` but apparently there is no such option or I am making a mistake.

https://jsfiddle.net/gmjy04Lf/

If this is not available for slider-thumb, how can I further decorate it?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Comment: Inputs don't allow for :before and :after pseudo elements, you'll have to try a different way. – Jesse Kernaghan Jan 26 '15 at 22:30

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159866/style-input-range-before-and-after

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style input range before and after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159866/style-input-range-before-and-after)